# Create Azure VM with Premium Storage and Public Static IP Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to create a DS Series VM in Azure using premium storage and assign it a static public IP.  From what I have read you can no longer assign a public static IP to a resource group (it only works with the older service groups).  I have created a Powershell script that attempts to create a load balancer and assign a new VM to the load balancer.  In theory the load balancer can get assigned the public static IP and traffic would get routed to the VM.  The script appears to run and the VM is created but it will not Start.  The status of the VM is listed as Failed.  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong in this script?

```
Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager

Add-AzureAccount

$subscr="mysubscription" Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscr

$rgName="testRG" $locName="West US" New-AzureResourceGroup -Name $rgName -Location $locName

$saName="teststorage" $saType="Premium_LRS" New-AzureStorageAccount
-Name $saName -ResourceGroupName $rgName –Type $saType -Location $locName

$frontendSubnet=New-AzureVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name "testfrontendSubnet" -AddressPrefix 10.0.1.0/24 $backendSubnet=New-AzureVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name "testbackendSubnet" -AddressPrefix 10.0.2.0/24 New-AzurevirtualNetwork
-Name "testVNet" -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $locName -AddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/16 -Subnet $frontendSubnet,$backendSubnet

$publicIP = New-AzurePublicIpAddress -Name "testPublicIp"
-ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $locName –AllocationMethod Static -DomainNameLabel "testIP" $frontendIP = New-AzureLoadBalancerFrontendIpConfig -Name "test-LB-Frontend"
-PublicIpAddress $publicIP  $beaddresspool= New-AzureLoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolConfig -Name "test-LB-backend" $lbrule = New-AzureLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name "HTTP"
-FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP -BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool -Protocol Tcp -FrontendPort 80 -BackendPort 80 $NRPLB = New-AzureLoadBalancer -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name "test-LB"
-Location $locName -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP -LoadBalancingRule $lbrule -BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool 

$nicName="test-NIC" $lbName="test-LB" $bePoolIndex=0 $vnetName="testVNet" $subnetIndex=0 $natRuleIndex=0 $vnet=Get-AzurevirtualNetwork -Name $vnetName -ResourceGroupName $rgName $lb=Get-AzureLoadBalancer -Name $lbName -ResourceGroupName $rgName 

$backendSubnet = Get-AzureVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name "testbackendSubnet" -VirtualNetwork $vnet $nic=New-AzureNetworkInterface -Name $nicName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $locName -Subnet $backendSubnet
-LoadBalancerBackendAddressPool $lb.BackendAddressPools[$bePoolIndex] -LoadBalancerInboundNatRule $lb.InboundNatRules[$natRuleIndex]

# TWO OTHERS I'VE TRIED WITHOUT SUCCESS
# $nic=New-AzureNetworkInterface -Name $nicName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $locName -Subnet $backendSubnet
-LoadBalancerBackendAddressPool $lb.BackendAddressPools[$bePoolIndex]
# $nic=New-AzureNetworkInterface -Name $nicName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $locName -Subnet $vnet.Subnets[$subnetIndex].Id
-LoadBalancerBackendAddressPool $lb.BackendAddressPools[$bePoolIndex]

$vmName="test" $vmSize="Standard_DS2" $vm=New-AzureVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize $vmSize

$pubName="MicrosoftWindowsServer" $offerName="WindowsServer" $skuName="2012-R2-Datacenter" $cred=Get-Credential -Message "Type the name and password of the local administrator account." $vm=Set-AzureVMOperatingSystem -VM $vm -Windows -ComputerName $vmName
-Credential $cred -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate $vm=Set-AzureVMSourceImage -VM $vm -PublisherName $pubName -Offer $offerName -Skus $skuName -Version "latest" $vm=Add-AzureVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id

$diskName="test-OSDisk" $storageAcc=Get-AzureStorageAccount
-ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $saName $osDiskUri=$storageAcc.PrimaryEndpoints.Blob.ToString() + "vhds/" + $diskName  + ".vhd" $vm=Set-AzureVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name $diskName
-VhdUri $osDiskUri -CreateOption fromImage New-AzureVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $locName -VM $vm
```

Comment: Have you gone into the portal to look at your created resource group, to see which items within the resource group have, and have not, been created? Do you see your new storage account? If so: Do you see your OS disk under /vhds in your new storage account? Pls edit your answer to clarify.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the location West US and Azure is having severe capacity issues with DS series VMs using Premium storage in East US 2 and West US since a couple of days.

Sadly this problem have not been mentioned the Azure status page.

Try to use another location that support Premium storage, like West Europe and your VM should create and start normally.

Comment: This type of answer isn't a valid answer, especially if what you say is true (that there's a capacity issue), as it would be a transient service issue. Further: You don't know that's the actual issue. At best, this should have been a comment.

Comment: I'll know next time that we can just comment on a question. thanks

Comment: Thanks Stephane!!!!  I re-ran the same script in West Europe and the VM started right up.  I still need to take a closer look to make sure everything is working correctly.  I'm trying to access the VM via a public IP.  Hopefully the script is correct and I will be able to do that.  I'll test out more next week.  Thanks again, glad the VM at least started...I would think fixing the West US and East US2 facilities will be a major priority so hope it is not down too long.